# How do I handle the messy exception that is thrown by an async method?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Exception handling for asynchronous methods is a little weird.

If I write a synchronous method, it's pretty clear. For example, if I do this:

```
public static void Test1()
{
    ThrowException("Test1 has a problem");
}

public static void ThrowException(string message)
{
    throw new MyException(message.ToUpper());
}
```

I get an exception that is relatively easy to read:

```
MyException thrown. Message: TEST1 HAS A PROBLEM
Trace:    at Program.ThrowException(String message)
   at Program.Test1()
   at Program.Main()
```

But if I do something very similar, but async:

```
public static async Task Test2()
{
    await ThrowExceptionAsync("Test2 has a problem");
}

public static async Task ThrowExceptionAsync(string message)
{
    throw new MyException(message.ToUpper());
}
```

I get this mess:

```
System.AggregateException thrown. Message: One or more errors occurred.
Trace:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at Program.Main()
MyException thrown. Message: TEST2 HAS A PROBLEM
Trace:    at Program.<ThrowExceptionAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Program.<Test2>d__1.MoveNext()
MyException thrown. Message: TEST2 HAS A PROBLEM
Trace:    at Program.<ThrowExceptionAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Program.<Test2>d__1.MoveNext()
```

This presents two problems:

1. Man, that stuff is hard to read!
2. I can't write a `catch` block for `MyException` because it gets wrapped in an AggregateException. In other words, the following does not work:

   ```
   try
   {
       Test2().Wait();
   }
   catch (MyException me)
   {
       //This never fires
   }
   catch(System.AggregateException e)
   {
       //It'll go here instead
   }
   ```

Is there a standard way of dealing with this? I'd sort of would like the exception to be easier to read, and I really would like to be able to catch `MyException` instead of catching `AggregateException` and searching for it.

[Link to DotNetFiddle that demonstrates the issue](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FP6I4Y)

Comment: If you `await Test2();` you can catch `MyException`

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. The best option. Always use `await`. If you're using ASP.NET, there is almost never a reason to not use `async`/`await` through the whole stack.
2. If you absolutely must wait synchronously on an asynchronous method (and don't make that decision lightly), then use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. It will get the same value as `.Result`, but it will also unwrap an exception.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should use `await` with `async` methods: it will unpack the exception, save you from the deadlock and inefficient code.
2. Sometime ago I used [Ben.Demystifier](https://github.com/benaadams/Ben.Demystifier/) to cleanup traces, it might be useful for your case too.

Deadlock off-topic: `async` method captures current synchronization context. If you'll try to wait for the completion in the same synchronization context, you'll get a deadlock.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public Form1() => InitializeComponent();

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          => doSomthing().Wait();

   private async Task doSomthing() =>  await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

You can use `ConfigureAwait` to skip capturing the context:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          => doSomthing()
             .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false)
             .GetAwaiter()
             .GetResult();

   private async Task doSomthing() =>  await Task.Delay(1000);
```

[This article](http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/common-mistakes-in-asynchronous-programming-with-net/) covers this topic in depth. Feel free to read it if you are interested in the pitfalls of `async`/`await`.